# passing a string value to another controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am passing a `string` to another controller

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

CategoriesList *dvController = [[CategoriesList alloc] initWithNibName:@"CategoriesList" bundle:nil];

NSString *category=aBook.name;
dvController.category=category;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
[dvController release];

}
```

When I get value in `dvController` it does not show  I am setting that to button title

```
 NSString *title=category;
 [titleButton setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Not parsing, it is called passing iVars values.

Comment: Check if you are passing any value? Then check if you have properly declared `category` (like property and synthesizing), then again use `self.category`, while using `category` in it's same class(where it is declared). if problem persist still, response.

Comment: Have you set property for category?

Comment: invalid CFString ref it shows when i debug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is to create a custom init in CategoriesList:

CategoriesList.h

```
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController
{
    NSString *category;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *category;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil category:(NSString *)categoryName;
```

CategoriesList.m

```
@synthesize category;

...

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil category:(NSString *)categoryName;
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) 
    {
        self.category = categoryName;
    }
    return self;
}

...

- (void)dealloc
{
    [category release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```